# how to creating a like button for all posts with django and jquery?

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-templates

I want to create a like button for my django website with ajax.

I have already created a "Like" button but that button accepts multiple likes from a single user.

Now I want create a button which can take one like per user.

Comment: You have not shared your code. Although this question already has an answer, but sharing your code is better so others can point out where you have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have an AJAX request that sends the item being liked, and then process it in the view.

`models.py`

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False)

    def __str__:
        return self.name

class MovieLike(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('movie', 'user',)

    def __str__:
        return self.movie.name
```

`views.py`

```
class LikeView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        movie_id = request.POST['movie_id']
        movie = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)
        user_liked, created = MovieLike.objects.get_or_create(movie=movie, user=user)
        return JsonResponse({"created": created})
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('movie/like/', views.LikeView.as_view(), name='movie_like'),
    ...
]
```

`html`

```
<a href="#" class="js-likeMovie" data-movie-id="{{ movie.id }}">
    Like Movie
</a>
```

`jQuery AJAX`

```
document.querySelectorAll('.js-likeMovie').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var movie_id = this.getAttribute('data-movie-id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{url 'movie_like'}",
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", movie_id: movie_id}
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })
})
```